# How to stop directory browsing of a web site but also allow default document

Tags: asp.net, web-config

When you attempt to visit a directory on a web server you get a 403 message, whereas its generally more desirable to get a 404 message so you're not giving a hacker a clue that a folder exists.

I thought I had found the ultimate solution to this problem - by adding this to web.config system.webServer:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="StopDirectoryBrowsing" path="*." resourceType="Directory" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

This correctly raises a 404 when you attempt to visit a directory.

However sadly it kills default document mechanism at the top level.

Can anyone suggest a variant of the above that allows default document to work but still protects sub directories.

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't actually change the status codes returned but you can redirect as you like using `<customErrors>`:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/redirect/error-status.aspx">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/redirect/access-denied.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/redirect/file-not-found.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

you could redirect every status code to one single page if you wanted to.

Comment: The redirect directory is totally up to you; you create it and put your custom pages in there, which can be .html pages if you want.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a go and report back